# SQL many-to-many with relation status

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this problem:

Entities have a name. Entities can belong to multiple parents. Entities can have multiple children. Children can have multiple children etc. Entity name is unique.

Come with a solution that retrieves all parents, siblings and children from any given entity - but not the grandparents or grandchildren, so current depth +/- 1 level. The given entity is not returned in the resultset.

Sort the resultset by name and the relation status (parent, sibling, child) should be clear. Result set should support pagination.

Available tools are PHP 7 and MySQL 5.7

Yes, this is university task and you are not here to do my homework, but I am extremely stuck and would love some pointers into the right direction.

I decided to make 2 tables, with sample data as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `entities` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `entity_relations` (
  `id_entity` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_parent` (`id_parent`,`id_entity`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `entities` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Parent 1'),
    (2,'Parent 2'),
    (3,'Parent 3'),
    (4,'Parent 4'),
    (5,'Sibling 1'),
    (6,'Sibling 2'),
    (7,'Sibling 3'),
    (8,'Sibling 4'),
    (9,'Sibling 5'),
    (10,'Child 1'),
    (11,'Child 2'),
    (12,'Grandchild 1');

INSERT INTO `entity_relations` (`id_entity`, `id_parent`)
VALUES
    (1,0),
    (2,0),
    (3,0),
    (4,0),
    (5,1),
    (8,1),
    (5,2),
    (7,2),
    (6,3),
    (7,3),
    (9,3),
    (6,4),
    (10,5),
    (11,5),
    (12,10);
```

Now the problem is the query needed to get the desired resultset. If I am searching "Sibling 1" as my entity name, I should get the following data:

```
Name | Relation
-----------------
child 1 | child
child 2 | child
parent 1 | parent
parent 2 | parent
sibling 3 | sibling
sibling 4 | sibling
```

As the requirements state that it should support pagination I think that all should happen in SQL. I can of course make 3 different queries from PHP, one for the parents, one for the siblings, one for the children, merge that in an array and sort by name and then take a subset out of that array, but that seems to not be the most effective way. So I decided to give it a go in SQL.

So far I came up with this:

```
select e.*
from entities e 
join entity_relations er on er.id_entity = e.id
join entity_relations err on err.id_parent = e.id
where er.id_parent in ( -- children
    select e.id
    from entities e
    where e.name = "Sibling 1"
) 
or err.id_entity in ( -- parents
    select e.id
    from entities e
    where e.name = "Sibling 1"
)
order by e.name asc;
```

But that already doesn't work, it only gives me parents and not children. and siblings aren't even in the query yet.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Is my table structure good for this or should I do something completely different?

as there is no restriction in which MySQL tools I can use it means that stored procedures are also on the table, would those be useful here?

I really want to learn this, so an understanding on why certain choices should be made is what I am mostly looking for.

Comment: Why are just using sub-selects just to pull out the IDs? I would strongly recommend picking up a book about MySQL. Think of it as a future investment, since you will need it later anyway

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but "a book about MySQL" is not exactly narrowing it down. I am more than happy to do the work, to read the correct parts and trying to get to understand why this is not a good approach, but a bit more narrowing it down would be appreciated

Comment: Write one query per relation and use UNION ALL to combine the results.

Comment: You already have made a join.  Remove the `WHERE` conditions and just looks a the results (oh and make the table aliases more expressive: "e", "er" and "err" does not really make it clear which table there is the "children"). So, when you have looked at those results, simply try writing `WHERE children.name = "Sibling 1" OR parents.name = "Sibling 1"`

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an approach *without the names*:;

```
select e.*
from entities e
where e.id in (select er.id_parent
               from entity_relationships er
               where er.id_entity = ?
              )  or
      e.id in (select er.id_entity 
               from entity_relationships er
               where er.id_parent = ?
              );
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the entity *id*.

I'll let you modify the query to deal with names.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f70a0/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Why would this get an anonymous downvote?  It even has a SQL Fiddle that shows it working.

Comment: Because it is really terrible thing to do. And what are you showing is actively harmful to a newbie. Seeing something like this from a 500k+ user is really disheartening.

Comment: @tereško . . . Then you should explain and perhaps provide a better answer yourself.

Comment: I already did ... but I saw it as not fit for having a full answer and simply wrote in a comment.

Comment: @tereško . . . I find your approach quite inferior.  I say that as someone who has both written books on the subject of SQL and taught college-level courses on SQL.  I happen to think this answer is very appropriate for a student.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I now got this and it gives me the right results. But I can't help but wonder whether this is the "right" way to do it. All feedback much appreciated

EDIT: Removed many of the sub selects and using joins now instead:

```
SELECT e.name AS name, 'parent' AS relation
FROM entities e
RIGHT JOIN entity_relations er ON er.id_parent = e.id
RIGHT JOIN entities origin ON origin.id = er.id_entity
WHERE origin.name = "Sibling 1"
UNION ALL
SELECT e.name AS name, 'child' AS relation
FROM entities e
RIGHT JOIN entity_relations er ON er.id_entity = e.id
RIGHT JOIN entities origin ON origin.id = er.id_parent
WHERE origin.name = "Sibling 1"
UNION ALL
SELECT e.name AS name, 'child' AS relation
FROM entities e
RIGHT JOIN entity_relations er on er.id_entity = e.id
WHERE er.id_parent IN (
    SELECT id_parent 
    FROM entity_relations er
    LEFT JOIN entities e ON er.id_entity = e.id
    WHERE e.name = "Sibling 1"
) 
AND e.name != "Sibling 1";
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

any thoughts on if this is an efficient way to do? and if not, what could be improved?

For the sake of curiosity; would this still perform well if there would be an immersive amount of rows and relations in the table? Like, millions?

Of course I understand that in such cases there might be better options than (My)SQL altogether, but if that isn't available?